# Simple question on calculation of Fisher metric for $p(x,\theta)$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, solution-verification, fisher-information, information-geometry

The Fisher information metric is defined as:

$$g_{jk}(\theta)=
\int_X
 \frac{\partial \log p(x,\theta)}{\partial \theta_j}
 \frac{\partial \log p(x,\theta)}{\partial \theta_k}
 p(x,\theta) \, dx.$$

Say $p(x,\theta):= \exp \frac{\theta}{\log x},$ for $x\in(0,1).$

Then $\theta \in (0,\infty)$ gives us a coordinate on a $1-$manifold equivalent to the positive real line $(0,\infty).$

I calculated (confirming with wolfram alpha) the integral to be a Bessel function: $$\frac{2K_1(2\sqrt{\theta})}{\sqrt{\theta}} $$

But this calculation was done without the normalization constant. Also I'm not sure how to write my result in the proper form i.e. as a metric.

> Am I on the right track here? What is the correct calculation and proper way to write the metric?

I think I basically got the answer but looking for verification of the solution and additional feedback on how to write the metric.

Edit:

With the normalization constant included, I found the metric to be:

$$ g(\theta)=\frac{K_0(2\sqrt{\theta})^3}{\theta K_1(2\sqrt{\theta})^2}-2K_0(2\sqrt{\theta})^2+\frac{1}{\theta}. $$

I think this is probably the correct form of the metric.

Still unsure of the $jk$ subscripts and where they come into play in writing the metric properly.

Comment: What is $p(x; \theta) = exp\{\theta/\log(x)\}$ when $\theta \in R^n$?

Comment: @xzm I'm not sure of that

Comment: The fact that you have $\partial/\partial\theta_i$ and $\partial/\partial\theta_j$ in your question indicates the $\theta$ you're dealing with is something like $\theta_1, \dots, \theta_n$. This is what @xzm is saying.

Comment: @Aruralreader oh I'm dealing with  a one parameter distribution with, $\theta$ as the parameter. So I guess it's just $\theta=\theta_1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your probability density function is
$$ p(x;\theta) = \frac{\exp(\theta/\log x)}{2\sqrt{\theta}K_1(2\sqrt{\theta})}, $$
i.e., proportional to the one you proposed, but with the normalisation constant.

The expression for the Fisher metric as you wrote is general for a distribution parametrised by a vector $\theta = (\theta^1, \dots, \theta^n)$ in some open set $\Theta \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. In that expression, the indices vary as $1 \le j,k \le n$.

You are right in your comment: in this case the parametrisation is one-dimensional, so that the metric has only one element, namely $g_{11}(\theta)$.

I tried quickly computing it with Mathematica, but found something slightly different:
$$ g_{11}(\theta) = \frac{K_1(2\sqrt{\theta})^2 - K_0(2\sqrt{\theta})^2}{\theta K_1(2\sqrt{\theta})^2}. $$

This does not seem equivalent to your solution. Maybe you should double check it.

Comment: Do you know if the Fisher metric of an unnormalized probability distribution is still a metric? Or does it have to be a normalized probability distribution?

Comment: It seems to me that the "Fisher matrix" of a parametric function with finite integral (what you call unnormalised probability distribution) still is symmetric and positive-definite, so that it can define a Riemannian metric. But I don't know if this metric would enjoy the nice properties that make the (true) Fisher metric the natural choice for statistical manifolds.